# How to get the onedrive files that were Shared with me using JSOM or REST or in SPFx

Tags: rest, spfx, microsoft-graph

Is there any api available in REST or JSOM to bring the shared documents to me in SharePoint using SPFx framework.
I came to know that we can get details with [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). 
But I am more interested in simple REST queries instead of passing OAuth process in Graph API. 
Am I in right way?

Answer (score 0):

SPFx provides an inbuilt `graphHttpclient` to make Graph API calls.

It has enough permissions (`Group.ReadWrite.All,
Reports.Read.All`) to fetch the files shared with you with making any extra auth call. This will fetch all the files shared with you from both Onedrive and SharePoint.

You can use the below code:

```
private _getFilesSharedWithMe(): Promise<any> {

    return this.context.graphHttpClient.get(`v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe`, GraphHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        console.warn(response.statusText);
      }
    }).then((respJSON: any) => {
      console.log(respJSON);      
      return respJSON;
    });

 }
```

**Usage**

```
var filesSharedWithMe = this._getFilesSharedWithMe();
filesSharedWithMe.then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

You need to add the below import statement:

```
import {GraphHttpClient,HttpClientResponse} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

However, do note that `graphHttpClient` is currently is in preview and will be deprecated in the future SPFx release. You can use `AadHttpClient` or `MSGraphClient` in the future which will be the replacement for `graphHttpClient`.

Reference - [Call microsoft graph using graphhttpclient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/call-microsoft-graph-using-graphhttpclient)

Comment: Hey @Mihir, did you try the above code ? is it working for you ? If yes, could you please mark it as answer, thanks, cheers !